# download files from ftp to local drive

Tags: ftp

In FTP Sub Folder contains some csv files want to download into local drive folder within one csv file.
In FTP each csv file contains only one record.So,Now i want  get all 5 records into localdrive folder in one csv file.Here is code works only for one csv file.

```
   private void DownloadFile(string userName, string password, string ftpSourceFilePath, string localDestinationFilePath)
   {
       //FileStream responseStream =null;
        int Length = 2048;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];


     //   int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpSourceFilePath, userName, password, false);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localDestinationFilePath, FileMode.Create);

        while (true )
        {
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;


            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        fileStream.Close();
    }
    private FtpWebRequest CreateFtpWebRequest(string ftpDirectoryPath, string userName, string password, bool keepAlive)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpDirectoryPath));

        //Set proxy to null. Under current configuration if this option is not set then the proxy that is used will get an html response from the web content gateway (firewall monitoring system)
        request.Proxy = null;

        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = keepAlive;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        return request;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadFile("Username1", "Password1", "ftp://172.32.1.252:5010/Test/CBRE/building.csv", "C://Workspace/ex.csv");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly what you are trying to do, but you can try this wat too:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile(http://www.domain.com/files/yourfile.ext, " yourfile.ext");
```

[WebClientClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)